# Saving multiply pdf plots r

Tags: r, loops, pdf, save

I have made a loop for making multiply plots, however i have no way of saving them, my code looks like this:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# RING data: Mikkel
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Set working directory
setwd()

#### Read data & Converting factors ####
dat <- read.table("Complete RING.txt", header =TRUE)  
str(dat)
dat$Vial <- as.factor(dat$Vial)
dat$Line <- as.factor(dat$Line)
dat$Fly <- as.factor(dat$Fly)  
dat$Temp <- as.factor(dat$Temp)
str(dat)

datSUM <- summaryBy(X0.5_sec+X1_sec+X1.5_sec+X2_sec+X2.5_sec+X3_sec~Vial_nr+Concentration+Sex+Line+Vial+Temp,data=dat, FUN=sum)
fl<-levels(datSUM$Line)

colors = c("#e41a1c", "#377eb8", "#4daf4a", "#984ea3")

meltet <- melt(datSUM, id=c("Concentration","Sex","Line","Vial", "Temp", "Vial_nr"))

levels(meltet$variable) <- c('0,5 sec', '1 sec', '1,5 sec', '2 sec', '2,5 sec', '3 sec')

meltet20 <- subset(meltet, Line=="20")
meltet20$variable <- as.factor(meltet20$variable)

AllConcentrations <- levels(meltet20$Concentration)

for (i in AllConcentrations) {
  meltet.i <- meltet20[meltet20$Concentration ==i,]
  quartz()
  print(dotplot(value~variable|Temp, group=Sex, data = meltet.i ,xlab="Time", ylab="Total height pr vial [mm above buttom]", main=paste('Line 20 concentration ', meltet.i$Concentration[1]),
                key = list(points = list(col = colors[1:2], pch = c(1, 2)),
                           text = list(c("Female", "Male")),
                           space = "top"), col = colors, pch =c(1, 2))) }
```

I have tried with the quartz.save function, but that just overwrites the files. Im using a mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: Does [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26811291/496488) help?

Comment: No now i just get a pdf file with no content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to save multiple plots in a loop I tend to do something like...

```
for(i in AllConcentrations){

meltet.i <- meltet20[meltet20$Concentration ==i,]

pdf(paste("my_filename", i, ".pdf", sep = ""))
  dotplot(value~variable|Temp, group=Sex, data = meltet.i ,xlab="Time", ylab="Total height pr vial [mm above buttom]", main=paste('Line 20 concentration ', meltet.i$Concentration[1]),
            key = list(points = list(col = colors[1:2], pch = c(1, 2)),
                       text = list(c("Female", "Male")),
                       space = "top"), col = colors, pch =c(1, 2))
dev.off()
}
```

This will create a pdf file for every level in `AllConcentrations` and save it in your working directory.  It will paste together `my_filename`, the number of the iteration `i`, and then `.pdf` together to make each file unique.  Of course, you will want to adjust height and width in the `pdf` function.

Comment: I can make it save the files as a pdf, but it's just an empty pdf?

Comment: That may have to do with the fact that you are doing this on a mac? Try adding the `print` function around `dotplot` like you have in your example.